# How to add the anchoring for the apex interactive grid column link builder

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-19.2

I want to click the column in APEX Interactive grid. It should go the Classic report in the same page. I gave the anchor value in the Link Builder - Target. But it is going to the top of the page, not the classic report region. How to give the anchor for the Interactive grid?

Can anybody please provide the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set focus for a specific region.

```
var region = apex.region( "myRegion" );
region.focus();

or 
<body onLoad="javascript:setFocus('P4_USERNAME');">
or
```

You can use set Focus dynamic action to set focus for item/tegion etc.

Comment: I have used region.Focus(). It is working fine. Thanks for the answer.